# Why does freshly slaughtered chicken needs to be cooled down before cooking?

Tags: chicken

Today I bought a chicken that was slaughtered less than an hour before, so it was still warm. The shopkeeper said it needs to stay in the freezer for a couple of hours to cool off before I proceeded with cooking. Why is that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The consensus from sites I have seen that appear fairly credible is that you need a resting period to avoid toughness in the final product.  I speculate this is to allow [rigor mortis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigor_mortis) to come and go.

According to Girl's Guide to Butter's article *[Chicken Butchering 101](http://girlsguidetobutter.com/2010/08/chicken-butchering-101/)*:

> And now the final step in the butchering process – put them in a
>   larger tub filled with cold water (ours comes straight from the ground
>   and is very cold), and let them sit and relax till the evening (if
>   you’ve butchered in the morning) or overnight ...
>
> Note that it is important to let your chickens rest and relax in this
>   fashion before cooking them, because, if you cook them right away (not
>   that most of you, unlike me, would want to), they are likely to be
>   tough.

Similarly, The Self Sufficient Home Acre's *[How to Butcher a Chicken](http://www.theselfsufficienthomeacre.com/2013/02/how-to-butcher-a-chicken-5.html)* article says:

> [P]ut it in the refrigerator for 24 hours before cooking. If the meat
>   is not allowed to relax, it will be tough. If you plan to freeze the
>   chicken, you can leave it in the refrigerator overnight or you can
>   freeze it right away. Just be sure to pull the frozen bird out and let
>   it thaw completely before cooking it. I have had good luck with this
>   method.